# Room library can copy db from asset folder?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have old project with Pre-loaded database in Assets folder. The project have [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) implemented for database operations. But now to update app I want to move my project to [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) database library.

So my question is, Is there any method or feature available in Room library with I can use preloaded db file in app at runtime.

Or Is any way I can load db first and then from Room library I can directly execute queries on that db?

Comment: (Please do not add voting advice or commentary to questions, thank you - it is not of interest to most users. Put it in the comments if you need to).

Comment: Ok but some users gives their sh*t here without explanation so.

Comment: It happens. It has long been held on _Meta_ that: _users may vote for any reason they like, up or down, anonymously or not as they choose, as long as they do not serial-vote on a single user_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any method or feature available in Room library with I can use preloaded db file in app at runtime.

Starting with Room 2.2.0, `RoomDatabase.Builder` supports `createFromAsset()` and `createFromFile()` for setting up a database with pre-loaded initial content. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate) for more.

Comment: I am not using room library but thanks for solution. I will go with **DbFlow.**

Comment: Would you mind to update your answer to reflect the updated API, as stated in my comment below. Some people might only read your accepted answer and think this is the current state of Room.

Answer (score 8):

For future people possibly landing here like me in search of the answer - Room finally added the ability to load from assets as of [2.2.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0-alpha01)

Just put the database in assets folder (it can also be in a subfolder in assets) and access it like this:

```
val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
        .createFromAsset("/databases/database.db")
        .build()
```

If the database is not in a subdirectory, you just put the name without any additional path.