# Android Room Library fails to copy database from Asset

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to copy SQLite database from asset but it is not copying it is not throwing any Exception also

```
@Database(entities = [UserDetails::class, CircleMaster::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false

abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {abstract fun getLoginDao(): LoginDao

abstract fun getRegisterDao(): RegisterDao


companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var instance: AppDatabase? = null
    private val Lock = Any()
    operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(Lock) {
        instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
            instance = it
        }
    }

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        "Asset.db"
    ).createFromAsset("database/Asset.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
}}
```

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338939/room-library-can-copy-db-from-asset-folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got an answer from this link

[Room: Database not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619718/room-database-not-created)

`when I tried to insert data that time database is copied from asset and data is inserted` some people will face migration exception, I solved that by deleting room master table from the asset database.

Under the covers, by default, Room uses **SQLiteOpenHelper**, much as you might use it directly.

**SQLiteOpenHelper** does not create the database when you create the SQLiteOpenHelper instance. It will do so once you call **getReadableDatabase()** or **getWriteableDatabase()**.

From a Room standpoint, that means until you perform some concrete operation, such as invoking a @Dao method that hits the database, your database will not be created.